# Jade template as a preprocessor for html

Tags: templates, node.js, makefile, pug

I will not be using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) in production, but I like [jade](http://jade-lang.com/)s syntax, so I would like to compile [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) template into `html` when developing.

Given this file structure:

```
app/
  jade_templates /
    index.jade
    subfolder /
      subpage.jade
  html_templates /
    index.html
    subfolder /
      subpage.html
```

I would like to have a *script* that watches the `jade_templates` directory and compiles the corresponding html template to `html_templates` any time a change has been made.

How can this be accomplished?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
The Jade [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme) has this Sample Makefile, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to my needs.

```
JADE = $(shell find pages/*.jade)
HTML = $(JADE:.jade=.html)

all: $(HTML)

%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(HTML)

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I had the need for a similar script I took the time and tried out a few tools and shell scripts out there (like [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)) but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

So I went on to implement this solution. You can find it on github:

https://github.com/mihaifm/simplemon

See if it works for you. I added an example for jade as well.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for the response. Would you mind adding the command that would render the html template based on my requirement. I have simplemon install, but it doesn't seem to be updating on file changes.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: `cd app` then `simplemon -O jade html_templates jade_templates`. What OS are you using, I tested this on linux and win.

Comment: I'm on OS X. With your command I get the error `execvp(): No such file or directory` With the command `simplemon jade -O html_templates jade_templates` the templates compile when the programs starts, but not on changes.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly placed the -O. Ok I'll have to see what's going on with OSX, might be an issue with the fs.watch method of node.js.

Comment: Thanks mihai, please let me know if there's anything I can do to help debug.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for this.  Using [grunt-contrib-jade](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jade) and [grunt-contrib-watch](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch) you can fairly easily set up a grunt task to watch a directory for jade files and compile them to another directory when they change.

Grunt has a bit of a learning curve but it's super handy and allows me to feasibly develop in Jade (and Sass, and Coffeescript!) whenever I want -- if you're at all interested in this approach leave a comment and I'll add a sample Gruntfile that would do what you want.

Comment: It would be great to see a sample of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you write a little node app to do this.

The code would look like this:

```
// Watch a directory for files changes (such as here: https://github.com/Raynos/fyp/blob/master/src/build.js)
// Get the Jade code from the changed file
// Compile it
// Writes the output to a file with the same name in another directory
```

I said "node app" but it should be whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: I assumed that was the process, but I wasn't sure how to code it. Thank you for the link to fyp.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`entr`](http://www.entrproject.org/), which executes a program if one of the specified files change:

```
find -name '*.jade' | entr make
```